# Javascript/JQuery: Is there a way to append an image or text to an image that is downloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images on my project that users can download, but I want to add some pre-defined text or an image/logo to the bottom right corner of the image when they click the download link. Is there a method or plugin that might be able to handle this functionality?

EDIT: The images are not predefined - they are rendered as SVGs and I use [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) to convert them into a hidden canvas, then link them to that URL.

Comment: yes there is… You could use a php script which generates the text onto the image…

Comment: If you are talking about watermarking, note that you probably shouldn't be doing it anytime they click download. Instead, whenever you upload a new file, create two versions (one with the watermark) and just serve them the appropriate version.

Comment: The problem is, the images are not predefined - they are rendered as an SVG, then converted into a canvas object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about adding the text to the image that they download (like watermarking), it can be done in javascript, but it likely isn't pretty and probably not a good solution because the user could just download the image directly rather than using your link and thereby get the image without a watermark. Note that if this is what you mean, jQuery won't provide you any help here. But, there should be some JavaScript image processing libraries. The best option here would be to watermark each image on "upload" (whatever that means for your particular site) and to keep two versions of each image (one with the mark and one without), and then just serve the appropriate version when you need it.

If you're talking about laying some text over an existing image on the page that just happens to take place when they click the download link, then yes that's possible and you could accomplish it either with javascript / jquery or using CSS.

Since you are looking for a plugin, here are a few that google turned up (I'm sure there are more):

1. http://www.wbotelhos.com/capty/
2. http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/jcaption-a-jquery-plugin-for-simple-image-captions
3. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/23/jcapslide-a-jquery-image-caption-plugin/

Comment: The images that are being downloaded are SVGs converted into canvases, so it's okay that the user has the ability to download them without the watermark/logo, but if they use the download button, I want the image to download with the logo/watermark.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping two versions on the server and just serving the appropriate one. So, apply the watermark to a copy whenever you load the images onto the server.

Comment: Ah, but I can't know what the image will be, since it depends on changing data in the database.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to process it on download. Again, probably best handled by the server. You can point to a specific url with any applicable parameters and process the image and return the binary in the response.